# access to static variable of abstract class in child class

Tags: php, class, static

**Line**: `return 'Static hello ' . self::static_user . '...<br />';`
**Produces:** `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'static_user' in ....`

Note: Logic might be silly but I'm just playing wit it at the moment. Question is how can I access to static variable of abstract class in child class? I can access to public one `$public_user` with `$this->public_user` in child class.

```
abstract class UserAbstract
{
protected $public_user = null;
    static protected $static_user = null;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
    $this->public_user = $name;
        self::$static_user = $name;
    }

    abstract static function static_hello();
}

class User extends UserAbstract
{
    static function static_hello()
    {
        return 'Static hello ' . self::static_user . '...<br />';
    }
}

$obj_user = new User('Voodoo');
echo $obj_user->static_hello();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
return 'Static hello ' . parent::$static_user . '...<br />';
```

Comment: I can't believe myself. How did I miss that..... Always something little. I actually know I have to use $ mark but sometimes happens, what can I say.. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to use `User::static_hello();` but doesn't print anything. Not even an error.

Comment: @MadMax : why will it print anything when this function only returns the value??

Comment: I think I should go and sleep now ... Missed `echo` this time ;)